# How can I load a byte array into excel?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, excel, ms-office

I have a btye array that I would like to load into excel.  This will do this in vb.net with visual studio 2008.

How can I load the byte array into Excel via memory or with code?

Comment: Do you want to load an Excel file from a Byte array or do you want to view the Byte array in Excel?

Comment: I want to load a byte array into excel. This is done via memory and the excel application will not be shown on desktop.

Comment: From where do you want to load the byte array (file, another application via interprocess communication etc.)? And what do you want to do with the byte array in Excel? And what's your question got to do with ASP.NET?

Answer (score 0):

Here is code, you can try:

```
 Dim bytes() As Byte = CType(dt.Rows(0)("Data"), Byte())
 Response.Buffer = True
  Response.Charset = ""
  Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
  Response.ContentType = dt.Rows(0)("ContentType").ToString()
  Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename="
  & dt.Rows(0)("Name").ToString())
  Response.BinaryWrite(bytes)
  Response.Flush()
  Response.End()
```

Take a look at this very good article explaining every step. At the end of article you will find the code to get Byte array and then get the file

[Save and Retrieve Files from SQL Server Database using ASP.Net](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Save-and-Retrieve-Files-from-SQL-Server-Database-using-ASPNet.aspx)